# Switch DNS IP on Cloudflare on server unresponsive

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-apps

I have two servers, server 1 and server 2, they are mirror images. Different IPs

on cloudflare what settings do I use in this scenario.

Server 1 crashes - Cloudflare switches the DNS IP to Server 2 IP until the Server 1 is back online and it switches back.

Answer (score 0):

This is a paid feature called load-balancing

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005254367-Billing-for-Load-Balancing#12345679

it involves health-checks if a server crashes all traffic routed to available nodes